# Why can't I make PivotItems(1) visible?

Tags: excel, vba

I try to run:

```
Sheets("Hämtningar").PivotTables("Hamtningar").PivotFields("strFacilityNo").PivotItems(1).Visible = True
```

I get the error message:

```
Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class
```

Why do I get that error message?

Comment: Is the sheet name meant to be the same as the pivot table name? One says `Hämtningar` but the other says `Hamtningar` (no accent on the first letter 'a')

Comment: The sheet name is Hämtningar and the pivot table name is Hamtningar. So they are different.

Comment: I think the problem is that you lack " " around 1. Also see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotitems-object-excel